# Moving Point in x and y direction in python

Tags: python, matplotlib, plot, slider, point

Hello I would like to control the position of a point **P** in
**x** and **y** direction using a **slider**. The problem I have is that my point keeps coming back to the origin (x0 l y0). I've searched the internet for an answer to my problem but haven't found a suitable one. Thanks for the replies ps: Geogebra is not an option, only python

```
#imports
import numpy as np                 
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt 
from matplotlib.widgets import Slider
from matplotlib.widgets import Slider, Button, RadioButtons

# x and y variable for the point
f = lambda y: y
g = lambda x: x

#start position for x and y (x0 I y0)
x = 0
y = 0

# Select length of axes and the space between tick labels
xmin, xmax, ymin, ymax = -5, 5, -5, 5
ticks_frequency = 1

# Plot point P at the position (x0 I y0)
fig, ax = plt.subplots(figsize=(50, 10))
ptplot, = plt.plot(x, y, 'ko')

# Slider position
ax_x = plt.axes([0.25, 0.15, 0.65, 0.03])
ax_y = plt.axes([0.25, 0.1, 0.65, 0.03])

# Slider array for x and y and min and max value
xSlider = Slider(ax_x, 'x', -5.0, 5.0, valinit=x, valstep=0.1)
ySlider = Slider(ax_y, 'y', -5.0, 5.0, valinit=y, valstep=0.1)

# update for x position of the Point
# if slider changed update the x position
def update_x(x):
    x = g(x)
    ptplot.set_data(x,y)
    xSlider.eventson = False
    xSlider.set_val(x)
    fig.canvas.draw()
    xSlider.eventson = True

# update for y position of the Point
# if slider changed update the y position
def update_y(y):
    y = f(y)
    ptplot.set_data(x,y)
    ySlider.eventson = False
    ySlider.set_val(y)
    fig.canvas.draw()
    ySlider.eventson = True

# update on change / if slider is changed -> Update
xSlider.on_changed(update_x)
ySlider.on_changed(update_y)

# Set identical scales for both axes
ax.set(xlim=(xmin-1, xmax+1), ylim=(ymin-1, ymax+1), aspect='equal')

# Set bottom and left spines as x and y axes of coordinate system
ax.spines['bottom'].set_position('zero')
ax.spines['left'].set_position('zero')



# show the plot
plt.show()`
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem was that the variable x and y were only changed locally and not globally

```
    import numpy as np                 
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt 
from matplotlib.widgets import Slider
from matplotlib.widgets import Slider, Button, RadioButtons


#start pos
x = 0
y = 0

# Select length of axes and the space between tick labels
xmin, xmax, ymin, ymax = -5, 5, -5, 5
ticks_frequency = 1

# Plot points
fig, ax = plt.subplots(figsize=(50, 10))
ptplot, = plt.plot(x, y, 'ko')

ax_x = plt.axes([0.25, 0.15, 0.65, 0.03])
ax_y = plt.axes([0.25, 0.1, 0.65, 0.03])

xSlider = Slider(ax_x, 'x', -5.0, 5.0, valinit=x, valstep=0.1)
ySlider = Slider(ax_y, 'y', -5.0, 5.0, valinit=y, valstep=0.1)

def update_x(xSlider):
    global x
    x = xSlider
    ptplot.set_data(x,y)
    xSlider.eventson = False
    xSlider.set_val(x)
    xSlider.eventson = True

def update_y(ySlider):
    global y
    y = ySlider
    ptplot.set_data(x,y)
    ySlider.eventson = False
    ySlider.set_val(y)
    ySlider.eventson = True


xSlider.on_changed(update_x)
ySlider.on_changed(update_y)


# Set identical scales for both axes
ax.set(xlim=(xmin-1, xmax+1), ylim=(ymin-1, ymax+1), aspect='equal')

# Set bottom and left spines as x and y axes of coordinate system
ax.spines['bottom'].set_position('zero')
ax.spines['left'].set_position('zero')

# Remove top and right spines
ax.spines['top'].set_visible(False)
ax.spines['right'].set_visible(False)

# Create 'x' and 'y' labels placed at the end of the axes
ax.set_xlabel('x', size=14, labelpad=-24, x=1.03)
ax.set_ylabel('y', size=14, labelpad=-21, y=1.02, rotation=0)

# Create custom major ticks to determine position of tick labels
x_ticks = np.arange(xmin, xmax+1, ticks_frequency)
y_ticks = np.arange(ymin, ymax+1, ticks_frequency)
ax.set_xticks(x_ticks[x_ticks != 0])
ax.set_yticks(y_ticks[y_ticks != 0])

# Create minor ticks placed at each integer to enable drawing of minor grid
# lines: note that this has no effect in this example with ticks_frequency=1
ax.set_xticks(np.arange(xmin, xmax+1), minor=True)
ax.set_yticks(np.arange(ymin, ymax+1), minor=True)

# Draw major and minor grid lines
ax.grid(which='both', color='grey', linewidth=1, linestyle='-', alpha=0.2)

# Draw arrows
arrow_fmt = dict(markersize=4, color='black', clip_on=False)
ax.plot((1), (0), marker='>', transform=ax.get_yaxis_transform(), **arrow_fmt)
ax.plot((0), (1), marker='^', transform=ax.get_xaxis_transform(), **arrow_fmt)


plt.show()
```